# Display Error in Oracle Apex Application

Tags: css, oracle, themes, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have exported my oracle `apex` application and install on another computer. I used `css` file written by me on my application and also i have change some settings in `Theme` that i have used for my application. I have exported and installed that css file and theme also. but when i run my application, it is not display correctly. it display only `Texts` and `Images` that i have used in application. `Theme` is missing. but my `Login` page is display correctly. because it is not using my `Template`. `Login` page using `Login` Template in oracle apex. after logged, when i browse other pages in my application, they are not displaying correctly. Theme is missing on those pages.

The issue is with my `Template`. but i have imported it in to apex application.

How could i solve this ?

**UPDATED**

When i open the `Developer Tools` in my browser(chrome),  in `Matched CSS Rules` section in `Elements` Tab, display only `user agent stylesheet`. there is no my `stylesheet`.

Answer (score 1):

- Check your theme templates you changed and see if they are really correct and contain the reference to your custom stylesheet(s)
- Check the output of a page you know should have the stylesheet reference
- Where do you store the stylesheet? Workspace files, Application files, or simply in the "/i/" (#IMAGE_PREFIX#) folder?
- if the latter: did you copy over your stylesheet and is it in the correct location? You say you imported the application to another computer, so you might have simply forgotten to copy over those files.

Answer (score 1):

What is your Apex version ?

How do you load your CSS files ? They are stored on the server (accessible using the image prefix `#IMAGE_PREFIX#`), loaded into the database (accessible using `#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#`) or stored on an external server (accessible using the full URL) ?

When you say "install on another computer", you mean load your application into another apex installation right ? Then are you sure the server is configured as the other one (especially image prefix) ?

Have you checked that templates are the same in the two applications ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the console in Chrome or Firefox to check if there are any errors on your page, such as CSS files that can't be loaded.